# Custom UITableViewCell. Failed to apply UILineBreakModeTailTruncation

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am creating a custom UITableViewCell with UILabel inside.

When I am setting too long text into UILabel, it overlaps bounds of the cell.
Looks like I have specified all required properties of UILabel, but still failed to resolve what could be wrong.

Possibly I should configure a table or the cell?

Could you please advice the way I can fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the number of lines on the UILabel to greater than 1?  The number of lines defaults to 1, and if it is set to 1 then none of the UILineBreakModes will apply.

You can set the number of lines in code as follows:

```
UILabel *myLabel;
myLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

You should then find your LineBreakMode setting works...